# What can I do to make my opponent play faster at Regular REL?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, tournament, mtg-regular-rel

I play low-key Magic the Gathering tournaments, like release parties and Friday Night Magic. They're good fun but I'm often stuck looking at the clock, trying to avoid a game-3 draw. I know the problem isn't **me** because my sets against quick-playing opponents are usually over with 20 minutes to spare.

The obvious non-procedural workarounds are:

- Draft fast aggro
- Try really hard to win 2-0 so you don't need to play a third game

I don't exactly have the skills to do this consistently. :)

At higher rules enforcement levels, you can call a judge if your opponent is taking too long. That option's not readily available at Regular REL, though, and generally you're supposed to be forgiving of a player's inexperience or procedural missteps. Bearing that in mind, **what can I do to encourage other players to play faster without being a jerk**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm surprised that you seem to think there is no possibility of official intervention at Regular REL.  From a [recently updated official document](http://www.wizards.com/wpn/Document.aspx?x=Magic_The_Gathering_Judging_at_Regular_REL) on Judging at Regular REL:

> - General Unwanted Behaviours -
>
> There will sometimes be issues that do not have official fixes, but
>   need to be discouraged. These include, but are not limited to;
>
> - Players taking unreasonable amounts of time side-boarding or making
>     play decisions
> - Inadequate shuffling after a search
> - Asking for, or
>     providing, strategy advice during a tournament match or booster draft
>
> In all of these cases, educate the player on better behaviour – for
>   example, alternate shuffling techniques or the importance of allowing
>   players to make their own decisions. Players continuing to exhibit
>   specific unwanted behaviour after being instructed otherwise should be
>   issued with a Game Loss.

A Judge should be available to advise persistent time-wasters that, actually, there is a limit to how long they can spend "thinking about their moves" in a game of Magic.  Obviously the Judge will be gentle at first, as this is only Regular REL; but really, no one is being done any favours , if new players are not told early on that they need to play the game at  reasonable pace, that is to say, fast enough that a full three games can be comfortably completed in the time allowed.

Don't be a jerk about calling a Judge over, but equally, you shouldn't be afraid of doing so. It's not being rude to ask, in a neutral and polite way, for the basic ground rules of tournament Magic to be enforced.

Answer (score 2):

Being courteous to new and/or inexperienced players is important, especially in more casual settings.  Offer to answer (or find a third party to answer) any questions they may have if that's the holdup.  It is understandable to be indecisive about a crucial play, but it is also their responsibility to be courteous to you and not stall out the game (whether they intend to or not).

Comment: You're close to addressing the intent of my question, but I'd like some more specifics. Like, for instance, when someone's taking a lot of time to ponder an almost-identical board state for several turns straight, what are some behaviors I can adopt to courteously encourage faster play?

Comment: @Alex P - Its hard to get into the specifics because everyone will take things differently and it depends on how courteous you want to be.  Usually a simple "Are you done?" will let them know that they need to commit to something.  Other times you might have to get a bit more pushy.  At some point, they are doing you a discourtesy by continuing to take time doing nothing.